# Number of the current epoch in custom layer tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is my first time asking a question so go easy on me. I am trying to write a custom layer in python tensorflow/keras and in the layer I want to access the number of the current epoch of the model. I have extensively searched the tensorflow documentation to find something that could give me that. The best I could find is `tensorflow.keras.backend.learning_phase()` which return whether it is the learning phase or not. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a callback, check [keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/)

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback


class CustomEpoch(Callback):
    def check_condition(self, epoch):
        # TODO check if the condition is met
        pass

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if not self.check_condition(epoch):
            return
        # TODO do stuff
```

And make sure this is called somewhere:

```
model.fit(callbacks=[CustomEpoch()])
```